# which is the faster way to init function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, function

which one is the fastest way of initiating a function on page load ?

```
[1] - ng-init="myFunction()"

[2] - 
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(){
if($state.is('app.frontpage')) {
  $scope.myFunction();
}
});
```

personally, i like `#2`, but i dont know if it is the faster.

Comment: Keep in mind this from the docs, *The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat*, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: thanks for the highlight :) just sometime when i can't figure out how, i use ng-init instead :D